# JSON-Encoded POST/PATCH data in R

Tags: r

I want to make a POST to a webserver running a Rails application (I didn't develop the application, I just need to post to it) and I've been trying to use R with little success.

I've been doing this with httr and jsonlite:

```
install.packages("httr");
install.packages("jsonlite")
library(jsonlite)
library("httr");
url = "http://192.168.0.168:3000/api/styles";
b <- list(name="Lorem", description="Ipsum");
POST(url,body=b,encode='json');
```

Which nets me the result of actually being able to post but renders a warning from Rails:

```
Response [http://192.168.0.168:3000/api/styles/18]
  Date: 2015-11-06 13:20
  Status: 411
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
  Size: 307 B
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<HTML>
  <HEAD><TITLE>Length Required</TITLE></HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <H1>Length Required</H1>
    WEBrick::HTTPStatus::LengthRequired
    <HR>
    <ADDRESS>
     WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.2/2015-04-13) at
     192.168.0.168:3000
```

All other attempts at using other encoding options or content-type headers have given me a warning of 422 Unprocessable Entity.

I have however been successful at doing this in Python with this snippet:

```
import requests
url = "http://192.168.0.168:3000/api/styles"
payload = {'name': 'Lorem', 'description': 'Ipsum'}
r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
```

Can anyone shine a light on what am I doing wrong in the R request?

**Update 1: I've added the Verbose Option and the output**

```
-> POST /api/styles HTTP/1.1
-> Host: 192.168.0.168:3000
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.43.0 r-curl/0.9.3 httr/1.0.0
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Cookie: request_method=POST
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Content-Type: application/json
-> Content-Length: 38
-> 
>> {"name":"Lorem","description":"Ipsum"}

<- HTTP/1.1 302 Found 
<- X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
<- X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
<- X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
<- Location: http://192.168.0.168:3000/api/styles/19
<- Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
<- Cache-Control: no-cache
<- X-Request-Id: b5bbef5f-a627-424d-bbaf-892bf8aac758
<- X-Runtime: 11.910362
<- Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.2/2015-04-13)
<- Date: Fri, 06 Nov 2015 15:31:48 GMT
<- Content-Length: 105
<- Connection: Keep-Alive
<- 
-> POST /api/styles/19 HTTP/1.1
-> Host: 192.168.0.168:3000
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.43.0 r-curl/0.9.3 httr/1.0.0
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Cookie: request_method=POST
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Content-Type: application/json
-> 
<- HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required 
<- Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
<- Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.2/2015-04-13)
<- Date: Fri, 06 Nov 2015 15:31:48 GMT
<- Content-Length: 307
<- Connection: close
<- 
Response [http://192.168.0.168:3000/api/styles/19]
  Date: 2015-11-06 15:31
  Status: 411
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
  Size: 307 B
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<HTML>
  <HEAD><TITLE>Length Required</TITLE></HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <H1>Length Required</H1>
    WEBrick::HTTPStatus::LengthRequired
    <HR>
    <ADDRESS>
     WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.2/2015-04-13) at
     192.168.0.168:3000
```

Comment: without access to the server or knowledge of the API the only thing I can offer is that some webrick installs don't handle newlines in some header fields well. Can you run the `POST` request with an additional `verbose()` parameter and paste the output in a code block in the question? Also, if there is any public info on this API or a way to clone it that wld help folks help you.

Comment: I've updated it. I don't have access to the server right now so thats not an option at the moment and it's something internal from my company so It's not exposed (and yep, no info also). I'm still gonna try some more, but it's been some days and I haven't been able to pull it off the way I wanted to. Thanks for the help!